# Proxy Auto Config Web Test Plugin - VS 2012 Ultimate

Tags: c#, webtest, pac

I am hoping someone can help me with my problem. I've created a number of web tests which require a web test plugin in order to run. The issue I am having, is that our company proxy is via Proxy Auto Config file.

I cannot find anything about passing this in to the WebProxy object. Are there any other option for me to pass the config file or URL to the file so that my web tests will run correctly?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of trying different things, I've found the solution which works for me, it was very simple work around.

I used one of the proxy values in the PAC and setup IE to use it then in the advance options I added the URLs of the sites that I needed which are located internally in the exception box once this was complete in the Web Test Plugin I set up the following

public override void PreWebTest(object sender,PreWebTestEventArgs e)
 {
 e.WebTest.WebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();

and passed my credentials and now I am seeing the correct sites in Test :)